# EPSG1612 transformation

Tags: coordinate-system

I have survey data for contacts listed as eastings and northings - I need to overlay this onto PNG files but the location is quite far north - How do I apply EPSG 1612 transformation to the UTM Zone 32N so they appear as layers in the same place?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Can you also clarify what coordinate system you want to transform from and to please?

Comment: The position of where my PNG image was taken ( a view of the seabed interpreted from side-scan sonar) is north of 62 degrees.  There is a transformation from WGS84 using EGPS1612 code to ED50, but I can't work out how to apply it in QGIS.

Comment: You have to set up a custom CRS using `+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-116.641,-56.931,-110.559,0.893,0.921,-0.917,-3.52 +units=m +no_defs`. You find the values in the EPSG database, Table `Coordinate_Operation Parameter value` listed under code 1612.

Comment: Thanks Andre, have used the 1612 data from EPSG but when I click "Calculate" in the test section, QGIS returns and "inf" error code - Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates lie inside the area of use? UTM zones are not worldwide usable.